# Unable to get MS SQL Server paths using python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to get sql server data and log path using `SERVERPROPERTY`.

When I run below stmt in SSMS, I get paths.

```
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath') ,SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath')
```

But when I try to run the same query from python using pyodbc. it gives me:

```
result = connsql.cursor().execute(query).fetchone()
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('ODBC SQL type -150 is not yet supported.  column-index=0  type=-150', 'HY106')
```

Any idea how to get the paths in python?

Code:

```
 def getSQLServerPath(self):
        try:
            print("Into function..")
            connsql = self.sql_connection()
            query = "SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath') ,SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath') "
            result = connsql.cursor().execute(query).fetchone()
            print(result)
            connsql.cursor().commit()
            connsql.close()
            # return path
        except Exception:
            logging.exception("getSQLServerPath function: Something went wrong.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is actually telling you the problem here, it's the data type being returned that's the problem. The expression `SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath')` returns the data type `sql_variant`, which almost nothing apart from SQL Server supports. You can check this with the below SQL:

```
SELECT system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(''InstanceDefaultLogPath'');',NULL, NULL);
```

As a result, you need to explicitly `CONVERT` the values to datatypes that ODBC *does* support. As these are both file paths, an `nvarchar` would seem the correct choice:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(260),SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath')) AS InstanceDefaultLogPath,
       CONVERT(nvarchar(260),SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath')) AS InstanceDefaultDataPath;
```